# Get array out of a Json?

Tags: php, json

I am getting a Json respond with :

```
$response = curl_exec($rest);  
 $json = json_decode($response, true);
```

I manage to get its values(strings) with :

```
$foundUserId=$json['results'][0]['userId'];
$foundName=$json['results'][0]['name'];
$foundPhoneNum=$json['results'][0]['phoneNumber'];
```

But the last value- `phoneNumber`, is array of strings .

If i try then to loop over it i get nothing(although the array is there in the Json)

```
  foreach ($foundPhoneNum as &$value) 
    {
      print_r($value);

    }
```

What am i doing wrong ?

EDIT :
The json:

```
Array ( [results] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [action] => message [createdAt] => 2015-11-21T09:36:33.620Z [deviceId] => E18DDFEC-C3C9 [name] => me [objectId] => klMchCkIDi [phoneNumber] => ["xx665542","xxx9446"] [state] => 1 [updatedAt] => 2015-11-22T08:24:46.948Z [userId] => 433011AC-228A-4931-8700-4D050FA18FC1 ) ) )
```

Comment: Could you please post json data that you try to parse?

Comment: If it is indeed an array of strings then that should work. Can you add the (anonimized) output of `print_r( $json['results'][0] )` to the question?

Comment: `var_dump` the `$foundPhoneNum`, although I'm pretty sure that `$foundPhoneNum` is not an array. You can just `echo $foundPhoneNum;`

Comment: What does `print_r($foundPhoneNum)` show you?

Comment: @max  thanks- please see it in the edit.

Comment: When it is printing nothing, there might be a fatal error. Have you checked `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` ? So please post the whole code in the foreach loop.

Comment: var_dump on this array gives  "["+xxx65542","+xxx9446"]"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have json as a string inside json. That's why after `json_decode()` you still have json inside `phoneNumber`. You have 2 options:

- Decode `phoneNumber` like

  ```
  $foundPhoneNum=json_decode($json['results'][0]['phoneNumber']);
  ```
- Build proper initial json. Instead of

  ```
  {"phoneNumber": "[\"xx665542\",\"xxx9446\"]"}
  ```

  should be

  ```
  {"phoneNumber": ["xx665542","xxx9446"]}
  ```

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple of ways to debug situations like this as mentioned in the comments; `print_r()` and `var_dump()`.

`var_dump()`, although harder to read the first few times, is my favourite because it tells you the *data types* of each value in the array. This will confirm whether or not the expected string is indeed an array.

An example from the [var_dump() documentation](http://php.net/var_dump):

```
<?php
$a = array(1, 2, array("a", "b", "c"));
var_dump($a);
```

And the output is;

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "a"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "b"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "c"
  }
}
```

As you can see it shows `array`, `int` and `string` as the data types.

You might also like to install the [Xdebug extension for PHP](http://xdebug.org/) which dumps more useful error messages and tracebacks. Again harder to read the first few times, but well worth it!

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($foundPhoneNum as $value) 
{
      print_r($value);

}
```

There was an extra & before $value. Try this.

Comment: check `var_dump($foundPhoneNum);` before this loop. And please show the result.

Comment: it gives me : "["+xxx65542","+xxx9446"]"

Comment: Is it the full result of `var_dump`. var_dump should give something more in detail. At least what is the type of the variable.